# Converting XElement to XmlElement for XSLT transformation ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, xslt, xelement

I'm working on a project which requires me to load an xml document into xslt and transform it to display in an html table.  The problem is that because I am using LINQ to create the XML, all of the element tags are XElement tags, so the "xsl:value-of select" property wont read an XElement.  I'm wondering if there is a way to convert XElement to XmlElement or simply have XSLT read XElements instead of XMLElements?

Here is the code where I load data into the xml file via LINQ:

```
List<Prod> Products = utils.getProducts();   


  XElement xml = new XElement("Products", Products.Select(x => new XElement("Product",
                                            new XElement("ProductID", x.ProductID),
                                            new XElement("ProductName", x.ProductName),
                                            new XElement("SupplierID", x.SupplierID),
                                            new XElement("CategoryID", x.CategoryID),
                                            new XElement("QuantityPerUnit", x.QuantityPerUnit),
                                            new XElement("UnitPrice", x.UnitPrice),
                                            new XElement("UnitInStock", x.UnitInStock),
                                            new XElement("UnitsOnOrder", x.UnitsOnOrder),
                                            new XElement("ReorderLevel", x.ReorderLevel))));




    xml.Save("C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/WebSites/INFO451Final/Part_B/Prod.xml");
```

Here is the Code for my XSLT:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
       <h2>Products</h2>
        <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>ProductID</th>
        <th>ProductName</th>
        <th>SupplierID</th>
        <th>CategoryID</th>
        <th>QuantityPerUnit</th>
        <th>UnitPrice</th>
        <th>UnitInStock</th>
        <th>UnitsOnOrder</th>
        <th>ReorderLevel</th>

      </tr>          
        <xsl:for-each select="Product">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="ProductID"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="ProductName"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="SupplierID"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="CategoryID"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="QuantityPerUnit"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="UnitPrice"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="UnitInStock"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="UnitsOnOrder"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="ReorderLevel"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

      </xsl:for-each>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, right now all that loads are the headers since the "xsl:for-each" also doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've just done a web search for "convert XElement to XmlElement" and received lots of promising hits. Did you try that, and if so, what happened?

Comment: I have tried that, However, I haven't been able to implement the solutions into an html table, which is what I need to be able to do.

Comment: Well, is that due to a failure to convert the XElement into an XmlElement, or something else? It's important to be able to separate out tasks.

Comment: The common response seems to be to use the xsl template with node match.  The problem is that xsl template tag cannot be part of the <TD> tag in an html table, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**Just use**: `your.xDocument.CreateNavigator()` and pass the result as a parameter to the `Transform()` method of `XslCompiledTransform`.

**Here is an example exactly how to do this**:

```
string xslMarkup = @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
    <xsl:template match='/Parent'>
        <Root>
            <C1><xsl:value-of select='Child1'/></C1>
            <C2><xsl:value-of select='Child2'/></C2>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>";

XDocument xmlTree = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Parent",
        new XElement("Child1", "Child1 data"),
        new XElement("Child2", "Child2 data")
    )
);

XDocument newTree = new XDocument();
using (XmlWriter writer = newTree.CreateWriter()) {
    // Load the style sheet.
    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xslMarkup)));

    // Execute the transform and output the results to a writer.
    xslt.Transform(xmlTree.CreateNavigator(), writer);
}

Console.WriteLine(newTree);
```

**This example produces the following output**:

```
<Root>
  <C1>Child1 data</C1>
  <C2>Child2 data</C2>
</Root>
```

**For more information see this MSDN document**: **[Extensions.CreateNavigator Method (XNode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299124.aspx)**